# MS Access: How can I make multiple querys pull records from different tables into one list

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ms-access

Ok so here is what I am doing. I have a table named employees that lists there name and has a check box for different work assignments they are trained in, as well as what team they are assigned to.

I built a schedule form that when I select the team it only shows me the employees that are marked for that team. It also limits it to showing just the employees that are able to work in assigned areas.

SELECT Employees.Name, Employees.[Control], Employees.[Team] FROM Employees WHERE (((Employees.[Control])=True) And ((Employees.[Team])=Forms!Rotations!Team));

What I need to include is the overtime people signed up for that day as well to appear in the drop down list. I have a table that is "overtime signup day" and "overtime signup nights" it is by the day with up to 10 signup spots listed.

What I want it to do is to match the date on the rotation schedule form to the date of the overtime signups tables and add each sign up (each is in a different column, with the record being the date) to the drop down list.

Is this possible?

Thank you for your help, happy holidays.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in in your title:
Take a look at UNION SELECT to combine multiple queries in one.
(Although using UNION SELECT is considered bad practice).

Btw, can only be entered as SQL, not in the query designer

Comment: I'm very much a novice at access and SQL. Does anyone know of site or step by step how to do that?